# Template Haskell do variable assignment clarification

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I am looking at the following TH code, and have several questions marked by `--`:

```
newtype C a = C ExpQ

unC (C x) = x   --what is the significance of this

clift1 :: ExpQ -> C t -> C a  --why are the C's here followed by t and a
clift1 g (C x) = C $ do f <- g  --is the g an ExpQ? What is the f here, what does it signify?
                        tx <- x --what is the tx here signify?
                        return $ AppE f tx
```

As the title suggests, I am especially unsure where the `f` and `tx` come from and what they represent here. I think they are just variables being assigned values so that they can be used as arguments to AppE, is this correct? But in this case, why? Why not just simply call a function with these arguments instead of this whole clift1 do function?

Comment: `type ExpQ = Q Exp` so `f <- g` means `g :: Q Exp` and `f :: Exp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ExpQ` is a monadic value (in the `Q` monad) that gives a Template Haskell representation of some Haskell expression.  The underlying expression could have any type, so you could have an `ExpQ` that represents a boolean expression, which you could create using TH quotation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Language.Haskell.TH

boolExpr :: ExpQ
boolExpr = [| True && False |]
```

or by directly building it up from TH primitives:

```
-- almost the same as "boolExpr" above
boolExpr' :: ExpQ
boolExpr' = infixE (Just (conE (mkName "True"))) 
                   (varE (mkName "&&")) 
                   (Just (conE (mkName "False")))
```

You could also have an `ExpQ` that represents an integer expression:

```
intExpr :: ExpQ
intExpr = [| 2 + length "abc" |]
```

Note that `boolExpr` and `intExpr` have the same type, `ExpQ`, even though they represent underlying Haskell expressions with different types (namely, `Bool` and `Int`).  This is because Template Haskell provides an *untyped representation* of typed Haskell expressions.

It can be helpful to work with a *typed representation* of Haskell expressions, where the type of the represented expression is "carried around" in the type of the representation.  An easy way to do this is to define a `newtype` synonym for the `ExpQ` type that takes a so-called "phantom" type parameter:

```
newtype C a = C ExpQ
```

This defines a new type (or actually a whole collection of types, `C Int`, `C Bool`, etc.) whose values are just `ExpQ` values wrapped in a `C` constructor.  This means that we can define:

```
typedBoolExpr :: C Bool
typedBoolExpr = C [| True && False |]

typedIntExpr :: C Int
typedIntExpr = C [| 2 + length "abc" |]
```

where the `ExpQ` representations of expressions are annotated with the types of the underlying expression.  Of course, nothing actually stops us from writing:

```
badlyTypedBoolExpr :: C Bool
badlyTypedboolExpr = C [| 2 + length "abc" |]
```

where the actual expression type doesn't match the type annotation, so the compiler isn't enforcing the correctness of our type annotation, but if we use a little self-discipline to enforce the correctness ourselves at a few key points, the type system can help us keep the rest of our code base correct.

With that background, we can tackle your questions:

1. What is the significance of `unC (C x) = x`   ?

   Nothing, really.  It's just a field accessor that let's you pull the `C` constructor off a type-annotated `C SomeType` value to get the underlying untyped `ExpQ` back.  It could have been more concisely written:

   ```
   newtype C a = C { unC :: ExpQ }
   ```

   It looks like `unC` isn't even used in the code snippet you posted.
2. Why are the `C`'s followed by `t` and `a` in:

   ```
   clift1 :: ExpQ -> C t -> C a
   ```

   The purpose of `clift1` is to take an untyped representation of a function expression and a typed representation of an argument expression and return a typed representation of the expression representing the application of the first argument to the second argument.  For example:

   ```
   foo = clift1 (varE (mkName "not")) typedBoolExpr
   ```

   Note that, in this example, the desired type annotation is `Bool`, because that's the type of the underlying expression `not (True && False)`.  However, in general, the result of applying a function to an argument will be some other type.  So, `clift1` is prepared to take an untyped representation of a function expression (suppose it actually has type `t -> a`), apply it to a typed representation of an argument expression of any caller-specified type `t`, and generate a resulting typed representation of the application expression of any caller-specified type `a`.

   Since the function expression's type isn't specified anywhere, the types `t` and `a` are arbitrary as far as `clift1` is concerned.  We need to hope that where `clift1` is used, it's used in a type-sensible way, for example by attaching a type-correct type signature to the functions that use `clift1`:

   ```
   myNot :: C Bool -> C Bool
   myNot = clift1 (varE (mkName "not"))
   ```
3. Is `g` an `ExpQ`?  What do `f` and `tx` signify?

   Most TH processing takes place in the `Q` monad.  It allows you to do things like report errors during compilation, generate unique names, and a bunch of other things.  The purpose of the `do` syntax and all these extra variables in `clift1` is to construct the application expression within the `Q` monad.  Clearly, `clift1` was written by someone who not only had a terrible sense of what constitutes an informative function name, but also by someone unskilled in TH.  It can more succinctly be written:

   ```
   clift1' :: ExpQ -> C t -> C a
   clift1' f (C x) = C (appE f x)
   ```

   which makes it clear that it's just constructing a function application expression in the Q monad with appropriate wrapping and unwrapping with the `C` type-annotation constructor.

To sum up, `clift1` operates in the `Q` monad to take an untyped representation (i.e., a value of type `ExpQ`) of a function of actual type `t -> a`, applies it to a typed representation (i.e., a value of type `C t`) of an argument of actual type `t`, and constructs the typed representation (i.e., a value of type `C a`) of the application of the function to the argument which will have actual type `a`.